# Rails starting in dev, says server is http://0.0.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Ruby on Rails use 0.0.0.0:3000 instead of localhost:3000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478747/why-does-ruby-on-rails-use-http-0-0-0-03000-instead-of-http-localhost3000)

I am starting my server locally and for some reason I am noticing this line there:

```
=> Rails 3.1.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Is that normal? My /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1       app.cmply.local
127.0.0.1       api.cmply.local
127.0.0.1       m.cmply.local
```

But I had just experimented with taking out the first line there.  Could that have caused the problem? I put the first line back, but the server still says http://0.0.0.0

Any idea why that might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0.0.0.0 means that it's listening on all interfaces; in other words, anybody who knows your IP address can access your Rails application. This is normal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the standard address for your application when running the rails server command,
when you run that in the terminal you'll see:

```
$ cd commandsapp
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

the line:

```
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

is letting you know that your app will be viewable at said address in your browser.

check out the railsguides link I posted for more info.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html