# Connect to application address via browser in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can not connect to the application address via browser (`This site can’t be reached 0.0.0.0 refused to connect`.) when starting rails project, in development environment everything works fine.

```
> rails server -P /tmp/puma -e production
> => Booting Puma
> => Rails 5.0.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
> => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options [DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead Puma starting
> in single mode...
> * Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
> * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
> * Environment: production
> * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000 Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

My database.yml :

```
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host:     localhost
  database: magnetcoin_production
  pool:     10
  timeout:  10000
  username: magnetcoin
  password: magnetcoin
  template: template0


development:
  <<: *default
  database: magnetcoin_development

test:
  <<: *default
  data
```

base: magnetcoin_test

Comment: Use `rails s  -e production`

Comment: I tried this before, same thing

Comment: What issue do you face by doing so?

Comment: I seemed this in tutorial

Comment: @Yevgen
try connect with url http://localhost:3000/
Question and answer with more information:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478747/why-does-ruby-on-rails-use-http-0-0-0-03000-instead-of-http-localhost3000

Comment: Got the same, does localhost and 0.0.0.0 identical addresses?